# Extracting large amounts of data from a website

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a large amount of data from a website. (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mleone/gdead/setlists.html) I am working on a data visualization project to display information about grateful dead concerts. I've successfully extracted and formatted the data I want, however the process is very slow. I am using the urllib library to open and read from each url. (There are hundereds of URLs). Is there a better way of doing this?

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

class Year:
    def __init__(self, year, dct):
        self.year = year
        self.dct = {}
    def addSong(self, song):
        if song in self.dct:
            self.dct[song] += 1
        else:
            self.dct[song] = 1

    def printDict(self):
        print(dct)

    def printYear(self):
        print(self.year)

    def getYear(self):
        return self.year




from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib

songlist = []

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
   return [value for value in the_list if value != val]

list_open = open("concert_list.txt")
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split("\n")

#empty dictionary
yeardict = {}

#populate dictionary with Year objects from 1972-1995
for i in range(0,24):
    yeardict[i+72] = Year(i+72, {})

# for each website located in concert_list.txt
for url in line_in_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
    newurl = []
    # find each link extension
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        newurl.append('https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mleone/gdead/' + link.get('href'))

        # parse through each full url
        for url in newurl:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read(), 'html')
            # parse something special in the file
            paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
            x = []
            # populate x by splitting the file into a list
            for p in paragraphs:
                x = p.getText().split('\n')

        # remove blanks from song list
        x = remove_values_from_list(x, '')

        # for each song in the song list
        for song in x:
            if(hasNumbers(song)):
                year = song[song.rfind("/")+1:song.rfind("/")+3]
            else:
                cursong = Song(song,year)
                #yeardict[int(year)].printYear()
                yeardict[int(year)].addSong(cursong.getName())



print(yeardict[72].dct["Truckin'"]) #song name
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a very deep question...way too broad for this site as currently posed.  I doublt that the `urllib` library is a primary contributor to the slowness you are experiencing.  Rather, there are many other factors that might dictate why your code is slow and how its performance could be improved.  But since you give no information or code to illustrate what you're doing, there's no way for anyone to offer a concise answer to your question.

Comment: A first step would be to profile your code, either with a code profiling tool, or just with a few print statements and time calculations, to figure out where all the time is going.  My primary question is how the time is divided between 1) getting the data you're processing into memory vs 2) doing the processing itself vs 3) storing the results of that processing.  I'd start there...figure out where the problem really lies in your overall solution.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for the quick reply. I've added the code to look at, so if you see anything glaringly inefficient please let me know. I will start analyzing the code myself to try and narrow down the problem.

Comment: can you post some values of `line_in_list` as a sample?

Comment: Right now it contains only https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mleone/gdead/72.html, which is url that contains the names and links to all the of 1972 shows. Later on I will change it to the homepage link that contains links to the shows from every year.

Comment: The code looks ok from a quick look imho, you should switch to `lxml` instead of `html.parser` though as stated in bs4 docs if you want better performance.

Comment: Doesn't `newurl.append(...)` followed by `for url in newurl:` mean that the urls added to `newurl` early would be processed many times? I guess this is probably not intended?

Comment: @ImperishableNight I think you're right, I checked it out and I think I shouldn't be using append there. I'm going to change my approach so that early urls are processed so many times. I bet that will speed things up. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this definitely sped things up. Turns out it takes about .16s for a URL to be processed. The way I had it before, every time I added a new URL to the newurl list, I was adding .16s worth of computation to the next iteration, which was growing quickly. Now, it only takes .16s per URL! Perfect!

Comment: Yay!!!  Love the community teamwork that happens here! - Given your last comment and that I've got lots of what-I-should-be-doing work to do, I'm not going to look at the details unless you have a new question about what you're seeing.  Is the speed you're getting acceptable to you now?

Comment: The speed seems acceptable to me. The URL handling might be slightly slow, but it's much more manageable now. It's always the user errors that get you :-). I haven't used urllib before so I had to wonder if it wasn't the most efficient library. But seems to be working for me now.